# Fortify : Cross-Site Scripting Reflected

Tags: java, spring, xss, fortify

```
@Controller
public class RestController {
  @GET
  public String returnString() {
     String str = "hello"; 
     return "hi " + str;         //here is the issue
}
```

Fortify marks string concatenation as Cross-Site Scripting Reflected. How to change this concatenation to make it not Cross-Site Scripting. I tried using String.concat, but still the same problem.

Comment: First, what is 'hello' that you are concatenating? There is no declaration of variable 'hello'

Comment: @Ironluca sorry, modified.

Comment: The code above is not vulnerable to xss. I guess the variable is a controller parameter in reality, in which case it is indeed vulnerable.